# How do I run a PHP script when I get a new email?

Tags: php, email, dns, gmail, hosting

I'm developing a web application which will send email notifications to users (including sender, subject, and message) if he gets new email in GMail. I can easily code for notification modules, but I don't know how to find and get emails. I'm having a free hosting account at x10hosting.com. I thought to create a email address in the mail domain of my x10hosting account and forward my emails to that address at x10hosting. Even if I forward it, how do I detect incoming emails and their counts, subject, message, etc. and how do I execute a PHP script which will take care of the notification module.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're doing. You're trying to email a user when that user receives a new email in GMail? That hardly makes sense.

Comment: Why oh why would you notify somebody via email that they have a new email?

Comment: Stackoverflow wants me to wear this question as a cone of shame!!!. Thanks SO!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about enabling the gmail account for pop or imap and using PHP to test that. You cant have a php web page that will automatically know - you will need to execute the script again and again to poll for new mail.

PHP really isnt the best solution for this.

Comment: With AJAX long polling (or WebSockets if you're not stuck in the 00's), PHP could work for this. Although I would probably choose NodeJS.